# after search result show multiple data on one table by user id and data id

Tags: php, sql

i create a search panel with multiple select value , search panel working but problem is : - 
my database table : product

```
sno |  productid | shopname
-----------------------------
1   |     one    | oneshop
-----------------------------
2   |     One    | twoshop
-----------------------------
3   |     Two    | oneshop
-----------------------------
4   |     Three  | oneshop
-----------------------------
5   |     Two    | twoshop
```

User Product Select Multiple in Search Panel .

Now Search User in Search Panel

User select Product ( one , two , theee )

Query is after search show all result

```
   SELECT * from product where productid = '$productselect' AND shopname = '$shopfoundproduct'
```

result found 5

```
  Result one
     productid    |    shopname
     ----------------------------
          one     |    oneshop

 Result two
     productid    |    shopname
     ----------------------------
          one     |    twoshop

 Result three
     productid    |    shopname
     ----------------------------
          two     |    oneshop

 Result four
     productid    |    shopname
     ----------------------------
          two     |    twoshop

Result five
     productid    |    shopname
     ----------------------------
          three   |    oneshop
```

and i want result is :

Result found 2

```
 result one 

 productid   |    shopname
 --------------------------
 one         |    oneshop
 --------------------------
 two         |    oneshop
 --------------------------
 three       |    oneshop 


 result one 

 productid   |    shopname
 --------------------------
 one         |    twoshop
 --------------------------
 two         |    twoshop
```

thanks ....

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag(s) for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Are you looking for the `Group By` clause?